# Why is my function not being called on click

Tags: reactjs

I have a modal component with the `closeModal` function, but i can't make this function work on click:

```
import React from 'react';

interface IProps {
  clearTodos: (e: any) => void;
  closeModal: () => void;
  viewModal: boolean;
  setViewModal: boolean;
}


const Modal: React.FC<IProps> = (clearTodos, closeModal) => {
  return (
    <div className='bg-white w-72 h-72 fixed top-1/2 mt-[-144px] left-1/2 ml-[-144px] rounded-3xl grid place-items-center p-6 shadow-2xl'>
      <h1 className="text-2xl">This will clear all of your tasks. You sure?</h1>
      <button className="bg-red-600 w-20 h-12 rounded-md duration-200 hover:bg-red-800 hover:text-white">Yes</button>
      <button onClick={() => closeModal} className="hover:text-gray-400">No</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Modal;
```

closeModal function:

```
function closeModal() {
    if (viewModal === true) {
      setViewModal(false)
    }
    console.log("I'm being clicked!")
  }
```

Yes, i'm a React beginner, and it must be something really simple but i can't quite figure it out. The code is really messy because it was my first project with React and i didn't know about separating the components in different files so i had to do that mid-project and it was terrible. Here's another relevant part of the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal'

interface IProps {
  closeModal: () => void;
  viewModal: boolean;
  setViewModal: boolean;
}

const Layout: React.FC<IProps> = ({viewModal, setViewModal, closeModal}) => {
  return (
    <main className="  flex justify-center flex-row bg-neutral-700">
        ...

          {viewModal ? 
          <Modal clearTodos={clearTodos} viewModal={false} setViewModal={false} closeModal={closeModal}/> 
          : null}
          
      </main>
  )
}

export default Layout;
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that i indeed tried to change the onClick property to both

`<button onClick={() => closeModal()}`

which after i click the button returns me this error: Uncaught TypeError: closeModal is not a function

and to

`<button onClick={closeModal}`

which after i click the button returns me this another error: Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-water-cm3cbe?file=/src/App.tsx Here's the full code if anyone wanna take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`closeModal` is being called in a callback function, but never invoked.

Either remove the callback, or add parentheses to the function

```
<button onClick={() => closeModal()}
```

or

```
<button onClick={closeModal}
```

**EDIT**
In addition, your `Modal` component is pulling out properties of the function directly, instead of destructuring props, like in the `Layout` component.

Change that declaration of `Modal` to this:

```
const Modal: React.FC<IProps> = ({ clearTodos, closeModal }) => {
```

Take note of the curly braces around the props.

Comment: Already tried that, if i change it like the first way i got this error when clicking the button: Uncaught TypeError: closeModal is not a function

And if i change like the second way i get this error when clicking the button:  Uncaught Error: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.

Comment: Ok, well then in addition to the issue mentioned here (you will need to do one of these), you also have an issue with the way `closeModal` is being passed down as props.  Please show the file you define `closeModal` and the entire chain of prop drilling so we can debug.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-water-cm3cbe?file=/src/App.tsx

Here's the full code

Comment: Found the issue, updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, i was so exhausted about this that i totally forgot to look at the basics, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<button onClick={() => closeModal}
```

To

```
onClick={() => closeModal()}
```